# Sum of series of fractions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the $f$ formula that returns the sum of the series created by fractions that have constant nominator and shifting by one denominator.

Here are some examples:

$$f(3) = \frac{3}{1} + \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{3} = 5.5$$

or

$$f(4) = \frac{4}{1} + \frac{4}{2} + \frac{4}{3} + \frac{4}{4} = 8.33$$

or

$$f(5) = \frac{5}{1} + \frac{5}{2} + \frac{5}{3} + \frac{5}{4} + \frac{5}{5} = 11.4166$$

or

$$f(200) = \frac{200}{1} + \frac{200}{2} + \frac{200}{3} + ... + \frac{200}{200} = 1175.6062$$

Does anyone have an idea on how to calculate the sum of this series?

Comment: What sort of result do you like to see? A software to calculate the summation, or a rate at which this sum diverges?

Comment: I would like to be able to calculate the 11.4166 in case I know the 5.

Comment: @thanos.a You could estimate it by using $H_n \approx \ln n+\gamma$ for large $n$. Here, $H_n$ is the $n$th [Harmonic number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) whereas $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to approximate quite well the value

$$k H_k\approx \frac{1}{2}+k \left(\gamma -\log \frac{1}{k}\right)$$
where $\gamma\approx 0.577216$ is Euler constant and $\log$ are natural logarithms

Here is a table which shows

$$
\begin{array}{r|r|r}
k & \textit{actual value} & \textit{approximation}\\
\hline
 10 & 29.289683 & 29.298008 \\
 20 & 71.954793 & 71.958959 \\
 30 & 119.84961 & 119.85239 \\
 40 & 171.14172 & 171.14380 \\
 50 & 224.96027 & 224.96193 \\
 60 & 280.79222 & 280.79361 \\
 70 & 338.29857 & 338.29976 \\
 80 & 397.23834 & 397.23938 \\
 90 & 457.43135 & 457.43228 \\
 100 & 518.73775 & 518.73859 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I consider this as a better answer since the approximation is quite well even for small numbers. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The numbers
$$1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n$$
are called the *harmonic numbers* and often denoted $H_n$. There is
no simple closed formula for $H_n$, but $H_n$ is approximately $\ln n+\gamma$ for large $n$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

You are considering $nH_n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot as this works fine for my cases which are in range of (200 - 1000). I will add these examples as well.